# Embed referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord.py

when I try running the code blow, I keep getting an error code that embed is already referenced even if I don't send the message ".help". Could any of you guys help me thanks.

````
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client=discord.Client()
cliet=commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('help.py sucessfully loaded')
    activity = discord.Activity(name='command watching for', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
    client = discord.Client(activity=activity)

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Title Here", description="Random Text Here", color=discord.Color.orange()), embed.set_footer(text="Inseart footer here"), embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url),
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing a language is quite bad if you want to make something with the language.

Here is a minimal example of your problem:

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.arg = arg

   def hello(self):
      return "owo" 

def my_func():
    my_class = MyClass(1, my_class.hello()) # here, you we are trying to use `my_class` while assigning it at the same time which leads to the error.

my_func()
```

a more normal way such error is raised is

```py
def my_func(x):
   if x > 3: 
      y = 1 # if x is less than or equal to 3, y will not be assigned
   return y # so what to return now? this will raise UnboundLocalVariable error

my_func(5) # works fine
my_func(100) # works fine
my_func(1) # oops, error
```

`set_footer`, `set_author` are bound methods of `Embed` object. You need an instance of it to use that. You would do these in separate lines

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.arg = arg

   def hello(self):
      return "owo" 

def my_func():
    my_class = MyClass(1)
    my_class.hello() # now works!

my_func()
```

I won't be giving you the correct code for your specific problem, understand your problem, and fix it yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've been learning python over the past few weeks but still need to up my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

See this line. (I added a few spaces to improve the readability)

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title Here", description="Random Text Here", color=discord.Color.orange()), embed.set_footer(text="Inseart footer here"), embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url),
```

What this is doing is creating a **tuple**, with a `discord.Embed`, followed by the return result of `embed.set_footer`, followed by the return result of `embed.set_author`. If we strip out the arguments, it basically comes down to this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(...), embed.set_footer(...), embed.set_author(...)
```

In basically every language, the right side of the assignment is evaluated first, and then set to the left side. This causes the method invocations to fail, because `embed` does not exist yet. You probably don't want `embed` to be a tuple anyway.

What you really want is this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title Here", description="Random Text Here", color=discord.Color.orange())
embed.set_footer(text="Inseart footer here")
embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

This creates the embed object first, and actually sets it to an `Embed`, and then runs the methods that set the other things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use the command line

```
client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None)
```

So there is not a default command message and you can use your own command.